# loop through a pandas data frame to replace existing values using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

**Problem:** I am trying to loop through a dataframe, row by row, by using a for loop. But its not working as desired. I know there are iterrows() and itertuple() by I want to experiment with for loop.

Can you tell me where this is going wrong ?

sample data

```
data3 = {"one":['101', '102', '103' , '104'],
     "two":['101', '105', '106', '104'],
     "three": ['102', '5', '107', '108'],
     "other": ['101', '102', '103' , '104']
     }
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

**Goal:** check column 'two' by each row, and if a  value of column 'two' exists in column 'one'
then create a new column 'new_col' with the value 'del'. If  the value doesnt exist in column 'one' then
create the 'new_col' as 'keep'. For example , if column 'two' has 101, i want to compare it with all the values of column 'one'

**my code:**

```
dfToList1 = df3['two'].tolist()
for x in dfToList1:
   if x in df3['one'].values:
       df3['new_col'] = 'del'
   else:
       df3['new_col'] = 'keep'
```

then I can replace the value in 'two' which matches with 'one' with a string like 'none'

```
df3.loc[df3['new_col'] == 'del', 'two'] = 'none'
```

**my output:**

Ideally in 2nd and 3rd row, 5 and 107 in 'two' doesn't not include in 'one' and therefore new_col in 2nd and 3rd row should have the value 'keep' but I am not getting it.

```
    one other   three   two new_col
0   101 101     102     101     del
1   102 102       5     105     del
2   103 103     107     106     del
3   104 104     108     104     del
```

**expected output**

```
    one other   three   two  new_col
0   101 101     102     101     del
1   102 102       5     105     keep
2   103 103     107     106     keep
3   104 104     108     104     del
```

Comment: Your goal doesn't match your expected output. You said you wanted `new_col` to be `del` or `keep` but your expected output has something else. Can you clarify?

Comment: you are right. updated it as asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to check.

```
df3['newcol']=np.where(~df3.two.isin(df3.one),'keep','del')
```

---

or to select by columns 'one' with any common value with column two:

```
df3['newcol']=np.where(~df3.one.isin(df3.loc[df3.two.eq(df3.one),'two']),'keep','del')
print(df3)

   one  two three other newcol
0  101  101   102   101    del
1  102  105     5   102   keep
2  103  106   107   103   keep
3  104  104   108   104    del
```

**Details**

```
two_coincident_one=df3.loc[df3.two.eq(df3.one),'two']
print(two_coincident_one)
0    101
3    104
Name: two, dtype: object


~df3.one.isin(two_coincident_one)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: one, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This works fine. Can you please give me a little hint how this one is better than the one suggested before df3['newcol']=np.where(~df3.two.isin(df4.one),'keep','del') .

Comment: Simply with `Series.eq`, those matching rows are selected between both columns. With `DataFrame.loc`, the rows of column 'two' are selected that coincide with column 1. Then with Series.isin, the values ​​of column one selected in the previous ones are selected (see detail)

Comment: While with the above method you mentioned only the rows of column 2 whose values ​​are present in column 1 were selected

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where`:

```
df3['new_col'] = np.where(df3['two'].isin(df3['one']), 'del', 'keep')
```

Result:

```
   one  two three new_col
0  101  101   102     del
1  102  105     5    keep
2  103  106   107    keep
3  104  104   108     del
```

Comment: my bad. it works. i tried np.where() but was not using .isin()

Comment: If this works for you, please consider marking it as the answer